# How to define XAML ancestor type in EventToCommand binding

Tags: c#, xaml

I have attempted to make a simple EventToCommand behaviour on a XAML switch using the Maui Community ToolKit which is not working as expected.

I have tried to bind the event to a command in my code behind which originally worked when originally binded to a button command but it does not work with the switch. VisualStudio is unable to debug and stops the program when attempting to display each Frame in the CollectionView but I believe the error is due to incorrect Binding on the EventToCommandBehavior Tag.

**XAML Code**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:LightApp.Models"
             x:Class="LightApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LightApp.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:DeviceViewModel"
             >
            <Grid>
                <CollectionView ItemSource={Binding Devices}>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Device">
                        <Frame>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label .../>
                                    <Image .../>
                                    
                                    // THIS WORKS
                                    <Button Text="Power"                                             
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:DeviceViewModel}}, Path=CommandToCallCommand}" >
                                    </Button>

                                    // THIS DOESN'T
                                    <Switch> 
                                        <Switch.Behaviors> 
                                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior

                                                EventName="Toggled"
                                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:DeviceViewModel}}, Path=CommandToCallCommand}" >


                                            </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>

                                        </Switch.Behaviors>
                                    </Switch>
<Closing Tags....>
```

**DeviceViewModel.cs**

```
usings...

namespace LightApp.ViewModel

{
    public partial class DeviceViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices { get; } = new();

        public DeviceViewModel(DeviceService deviceService)
        {
            Title = "Devices";
            this.deviceService = deviceService;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void CommandToCall()
        {
            // command here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously there is no parent which type is ViewModel... Find parent of type ContentPage and path DataContext.CommandToCallCommand

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I have updated code which shows there is a parent type of viewmodel:DeviceViewModel which is implemented successfully on a Button.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
<toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
  EventName="Toggled"
  Command="{Binding BindingContext.CommandToCallCommand, Source={x:Reference rootPage}}" 
</toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>
```

Note that you should define the x:Name for your page( x:Name="rootPage")